# How to customize Ext JS tree nodes properly?

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, tree

Ext JS 4. I have a `tree.Panel` where I want to display custom HTML in each node, generated from that node’s model data. I can do this by setting the node’s `text` when loading the store, but it is not the model’s job to do markup. So I created a custom `Column` that renders my HTML.

My problem is: unless I derive from `Ext.tree.Column`, it doesn’t show up properly (no outline, plus/minus icons etc.). If I do, everything is fine, but `Ext.tree.Column` is marked as private to Ext JS.

Is there some officially supported API to do what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have written a blog post about how to customize ExtJS 4 tree panel, I hope it will help: 
http://hardtouse.com/blog/?p=24

The idea is to use renderer combined with A LOT OF css magic:

```
columns : [{
    xtype : 'treecolumn',
    dataIndex : 'name',
    renderer : function(value, record){
        return Ext.String.format('<div class="tree-font">{0}</div>', value);
    }]
```

Comment: You use `treecolumn`, too. That’s what my question is about.

Comment: I see. Well, the ExtJS 4 TreeGrid Demo uses "treecolumn", so I figured it should be ok for us to use as well. here is the link: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/tree/treegrid.js

Comment: The link is not working. Could you check it or maybe a new link?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Note that the example above is missing a } for the function close and the second parameter is metaData, the third is record. See: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tree.Column-cfg-renderer for details and some helpful comments.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your answer above. Here is another example showing a few more options for formatting:

```
columns: [{
    xtype: 'treecolumn',
    dataIndex: 'text',
    flex: 1,
    renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
        // see http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tree.Column-cfg-renderer
        var tooltipString = "Hello";
        metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + tooltipString + '"';
        return Ext.String.format('{0} <span style="color:red;">{1}</span>', value, record.data.personname);
    }
}]
```

You might also want to add

```
hideHeaders : true,
```

to your tree panel config to remove the "grid" header that appears as a result of using a treecolumn.

Murray